# Google Ads landing site speed rating is low

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, google-ad-manager

I have a client which has a web site where its landing page scores 97 in mobile performance on pagespeed.web.dev. It also has 95 score on tools.pingdom.com

However, Google Ads give 1/10 mobile speed score for the very same landing page in Insights.
I have been investigating for last few weeks what could be the reason, but nothing seems to help or point me in some direction.

Site is done in WordPress.

Any ideas what could be the reason since I am out of any?

I tried turning off cache plugins and speed optimizers, as well as use different ones.